# Python search data within all XML elements

Tags: python, lxml

Newbie - I am trying to use lxml to find "error" in any element (sample XML file below, but it should work regardless to how nested the tags are):

```
<test>
  <test1>
    error
  </test1>
  <test2>  
    <test3>
      error
    </test3>
  </test2>
</test>
```

So far it seems that lxml is only capable of searching for tags and not the data within the tags - is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking if there's a built-in function to search the text in an element? It's pretty simple to write your own search routine using `lxml`'s `etree` parser. For example:

**test.xml**

```
<test>
  <test1>
    error
  </test1>
  <test2>  
    <test3>
      error
    </test3>
  </test2>
</test>
```

And from the command line:

```
>>> import lxml.etree as etree
>>> for event, element in etree.iterparse("test.xml"):
...   # Print the tag of a matching element
...   if element.text.strip() == "error":
...     print element.tag
... 
test1
test3
```

EDIT: If you end up going this route and don't need to muck about with XML namespaces I recommend you check out `xml.etree.cElementTree` instead of `lxml.etree`. It's included in the Python standard modules and is on par or slightly faster than `lxml.etree`.

Comment: If my input is a string, can I just use "ET.fromstring" instead of "etree.iterparse".